[Spring data couchbase]: Interprete rebalance events
For couchbase 7, Is there a way to handle rebalance node events within a spring boot application (actuator) ?
If the database is in rebalance, I need to put the application health indicator to DOWN
-- UPDATE --
In logs, I see:

com.couchbase.endpoint                    : [com.couchbase.endpoint][UnexpectedEndpointDisconnectedEvent] The remote side disconnected the endpoint unexpectedly

So I tried to add an event listener like this:
@EventListener()
public void handleCouchbaseUnexpectedEndpointDisconnectedEvent(UnexpectedEndpointDisconnectedEvent event) {
    log.info("Received unexpected endpoint disconnected event: {}", event);
}

But it does not work.

Are you sure this is because of a rebalance event? How often is this happening?

It is not related to rebalance.
It is nearly solved. I have just one issue. Using curl, I cannot request couchbases protocol.
Locally, this endpoint returns a response: GET http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/rebalanceProgress
while when I put the remote capella host, it does not work
Any idea ?

I don't think this is Spring Boot specific, but you can check the rebalance progress with a REST endpoint: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/rest-api/rest-get-rebalance-progress.html
Example request:
GET /pools/default/rebalanceProgress

Example response:
{
  "status": "running",
  "ns_1@10.143.190.101": {
    "progress": 0.1103515625
  },
  "ns_1@10.143.190.102": {
    "progress": 0.1095890410958904
  },
  "ns_1@10.143.190.103": {
    "progress": 0.3299120234604106
  }
}

"When rebalance has concluded, re-running the method returns the response code 200 OK, and the following object:"
{
  "status": "none"
}

However, rebalancing should not be something that requires your app to have downtime. From https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/manage-nodes/fail-nodes-over.html#understanding-failover -

Nodes can be failed over, and thereby removed safely from a cluster in the event of unavoidable downtime, without any break in the serving of data to applications.


In logs, I see
[com.couchbase.endpoint][UnexpectedEndpointDisconnectedEvent] The remote side disconnected the endpoint unexpectedly
So I tried:
@EventListener()
 public void handleCouchbaseUnexpectedEndpointDisconnectedEvent(UnexpectedEndpointDisconnectedEvent event) {
  log.info("Received unexpected endpoint disconnected event: {}", event);
 }

But it does not work.

The Couchbase SDKs handle rebalancing. You don't need to do anything.
Couchbase events are sent to the Couchbase Event Bus.  
https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-core-io/com/couchbase/client/core/env/CoreEnvironment.Builder.html#eventBus(com.couchbase.client.core.cnc.EventBus)
